# QML CheckBox set text size

Tags: qt, checkbox, text, qml

Is there a way to set size of text used in checkbox?

I have following code:

```
CheckBox {
    text: qsTr("Use Delays")
    checked: false
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    onCheckedChanged:
    {
        middle.useDelays = checked
    }

}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: According to the doc you need to set a [CheckBoxStyle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-checkboxstyle.html)

Comment: Did you try font? (`font.pintsize()`)

Comment: Which qml controls ? 1.4 ? 2.x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the `Text` item displayed by the `CheckBox` using [`CheckBoxStyle.label`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-checkboxstyle.html#label-prop)

```
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

CheckBox {
    style: CheckBoxStyle {
        label: Text {
            text: "Label"
            font.pointSize: 16
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For `QtQuick Controls 2` you can do:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-checkbox

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

CheckBox {
    id: control
    text: qsTr("CheckBox")
    checked: true

    indicator: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 26
        implicitHeight: 26
        x: control.leftPadding
        y: parent.height / 2 - height / 2
        radius: 3
        border.color: control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"

        Rectangle {
            width: 14
            height: 14
            x: 6
            y: 6
            radius: 2
            color: control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
            visible: control.checked
        }
    }

    contentItem: Text {
        text: control.text
        font: control.font
        opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
        color: control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        leftPadding: control.indicator.width + control.spacing
    }
}
```